# Get 80004005 (Unspecified Error) when connecting to iFix OPC server

Tags: dcom, opc

Summary: I'm trying to connect iFix OPC server remotely, but the OPC client get 80004005 (Unspecified Error).

**The whole testing environment is like this:**

1. The iFix 5.0 software is installed on a laptop (A), with Windows XP SP3, to run as a OPC server.
2. On the client machine (B), it is Windows Server 2008 R2.
3. Firewalls and Antivirus are totally turned off on both side.
4. iFix software is installed successfully. Because Matrikon OPC explorer together with other two 3rd party OPC testing tools can connect to iFix OPC server (Intellution.OPCiFIX.1) locally, on laptop (A); and can add tags and retrieve data with no issue.
5. DCOM can be regarded as duly configured on both side, because:

   - On machine B, using three different OPC explorers, I can get OPC server list on laptop A (means OPCEnum is working fine on laptop A).

   - Matrikon OPC server and another in-house OPC server on laptop A can be connected by OPC explorers on machine B.
6. The DCOM configurations for OPCiFIX on laptop A is like this :

   - Genral Tab: Authentication level set to "None"

   - Location Tab: Tick "Run application on this computer"

   - Security Tab: Users are already created on laptop A and granted proper permission. Because under the same configuration, Matrikon and another in-house OPC server is already working fine.

   - Identity Tab: Set to "This user", and specified the correct username and password. The input can be guaranteed valid, because I used the same setting applied to Matrikon OPC server, and it communicates well with machine B through network.

**The result:**

It seems I configured everything correct, I still get the error 80004005.

**Other ways that I have tried**

I googled for this issue, and then found this document:[DCOM Configuration when you want to use iFIX is OPC Server](https://www.google.com.sg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDUQFjAB&url=http://support.ge-ip.com/support/resources/sites/GE_FANUC_SUPPORT/content/live/KB/12000/KB12691/en_US/DCOM%2520Configuration%2520when%2520you%2520want%2520to%2520use%2520iFIX%2520is%2520OPC%2520Server.doc&ei=OPg3U5LFGIrGrAe1xoE4&usg=AFQjCNFxi06Qh3ZJ7XmV9LamGY1lEolMGQ&sig2=BSoZiLroA5hnJFzp2lpbwQ), and configured as per it's instructions, but still not work out.

According to the doc, on laptop A, OPCiFIX DCOM configuration -> Security Tab, when I grant "Deny Launch" to the specific user, I get 80070005 (Access Denied) instead of 80004005 (Unspecified Error).

Another try: On laptop A, OPCiFIX DCOM configuration -> Identity Tab, when I choose "The interactive user" or "The launching user", the OPC explorers on machine B then get this error message: *"The server process could not be started because the configured identity is incorrect. Check the username and password."*

**Seeking help**

So any body could tell where did I go wrong? Really appreciate for your help!

Comment: What does your code look like for connecting to the server?

Comment: Thanks for reply Claptrap. For Matrikon and another 3rd party OPC explorer, I don't have src code. For the in-house OPC explorer, I used to add debug msg. Then I can tell it returned this err code when I was calling CoCreateInstanceEx().

Comment: The error indicates that the iFix OPC Server fails, probably due to some server configuration problem. Use a test client, e.g. from <a href="http://www.prosysopc.com/opc-downloads.php">Prosys OPC</a> to validate that you get a local connection first.